# Prolog if/else statement with recursion

Tags: if-statement, recursion, prolog

I'm new to prolog and I'm trying to figure out how I can use if/else statement and recursion.  To illustrate, I've written a simple prolog program. The program is useless (in that its functionality is useless), but it helps me illustrate my problem.  The program takes a list, examines the head of the list, sees if it's the last element; if it's not, it adds the head to a temporary list variable and runs the program in recursion using the Tail of the list.  It should output the list in the end.  The program:

```
 gothrough([H|T], B, C):-
      append(B,H,B),
      (  (T == [])
      -> C=B
      ;  gothrough(T, B, C)
      ).
```

The call: `gothrough([sample, phrase, here], [], C).`

Expected output: `C = [sample, phrase, here]`

Current output: `no`

Any help on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: All of `append`'s arguments should be lists and `append(B, H, B)` can only succeed if H is the empty list. Looking at this code, it's hard to see why you think C is going to ultimately equal the first argument, or what B is going to do exactly, so I think you have deeper problems than just recursion.

Comment: You're absolutely right...I simplified the program and I forgot to set C equal to B.  But can you elaborate on the H is the empty list thing please?  I thought `append` appends the contents of B and H into B.  So for example, if B = [yesterday] and H = [today], then `append(B, H, B)` = [yesterday, today]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments I understand that you misunderstand how `append` (and Prolog in general) works.

This is not true at all: "if B = [yesterday] and H = [today], then append(B, H, B) = [yesterday, today]".

`append(B, H, B)` means "appending H to B yields B again". This is only possible if H is an empty list.

The key thing to understand is that both Bs in `append(B, H, B)` are the same, they must have the same value. It's like variables in algebra - all Xs in an equation means the same value.

You should use different name for the output variable, like `append(B, H, Bnew)` - then it will make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is `append(B, H, B)` which for most inputs doesn't make sense.

The second problem is that the consequence and alternative of an if-then-else, i.e. the parts after `->` and after `;` must both be Prolog goals (statements). `C` is not a goal. You may have meant `C=B`, though it's hard to tell because I find it hard to understand what your program is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, yes you are absolutely right.  I simplified my original program and I forgot to set C equal to B.  So I edited it in my original post.  But I am confused as to why `append(B, H, B)` doesn't make sense for most inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a no because append(B,H,B) fails unless H is []; remember, these are clauses, not assignments.  And since you never bind anything to C, it will never have a value in it if your statement was ever proved.

This will accomplish your task:

```
gothrough([],L,L).
gothrough([H|T], B, C) :- gothrough(T,B,Cx), append([H],Cx,C).
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!  Can you please elaborate on why `append(B,H,B)` needs to fail unless B is []?  I thought  if B = [yesterday] and H = [today], then append(B, H, B) = [yesterday, today]?

Comment: @pauliwago In Prolog a variable only ever has one binding, and functions do not "return" so what you're saying doesn't really apply to Prolog at all. I suggest you go back and start from the beginning.

Comment: append(B,H,B) fails unless H is [], not B.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done even more simply:

```
gothrough([], []).
gothrough([H|T], [H|X]) :-
    gothrough(T, X).
```

The first rule matches your empty list condition, which then forces the end of the recursion/the list to be built.

The second rule matches everything but an empty list, in which case the head H is appended onto X, where X is the result of list obtained from recursing the tail. ie. you don't need to use the append predicate - list appending is built into prolog.

```
?- gothrough([simple, phrase, here], X).
X = [simple, phrase, here].
```

This solution also uses one less variable.